# Cannot cast from Graphics to Graphics2D

Tags: casting, graphics2d, importerror

My program code is here:

```
package Chapter12;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Pv2 extends JPanel {

    public static void main (String []args){

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setContentPane(new Pv2());




    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    }



}
```

Eclipse shows this error when I'm trying to compile the code.

```
Cannot cast from Graphics to Graphics2D
```

This error occurs on this line :

```
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
```

Tried jre 1.6 and jre 1.7 - the same thing. Why the cast isn't allowed? I even tried to download some prepared codes and the error was the same.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this code as-is. Try refreshing your project. Maybe you have another Graphics/Graphics2D class defined in the same package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code is not broken and this cast is surely possible. The following code works:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Pv2 extends JPanel {
    public static void main (String []args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(200,200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setContentPane(new Pv2());
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.drawLine(0,0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
}
```

[image: Graphics cast works]

One of the possible explanations, you have the class named exactly `Graphics` or `Graphics2D` in the same package (`Chapter12`). Then, with imports as you have, this class will have priority; if it is not compatible, the cast will be rejected by the compiler. I was able to reproduce this by crating the empty class in the same package and naming it `Graphics2D`.

To solve, use explicit imports: replace your import statements by

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
```

This will tell the compiler which `Graphics` and `Graphics2D` do you mean. Even with confusing `Graphics2D` class, I do not longer see the error after rewriting imports as shown.

Comment: Writing `import java.awt.Graphics` will not help if he has another Graphics class in the same package. The Java compiler always searches the local package first, and only then the imports. Instead, he should modify the `paintComponent` method as `public void paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics g)`

Comment: It just does for me, determined experimentally two seconds ago. The error does go away. Try yourself.